# How to use data that is in a shapefile as another layer

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, basemap

I've got a shapefile with a large amount of different data attributes in. I would like to use the symbology of the base map to show income inequality as a %, but I would also like to some how over lay the crime rate for each given polygon. The crime rate data is also in the shapefile, I would like to display this as a heatmap or as a dot (which would increase when crime rate is higher). Does anyone know how I could separate the data out of the shapefile and add it as another layer ontop of the basemap, so I have the map displaying income inequality and crime rate.

I have attempted to duplicate the layers, but this has not worked as I would like the symbology to be a Marker rather than Fill

Comment: Just add the layer twice

Answer (score 2):

Change the *Symbol layer type* for the symbol layer of your duplicated layer to *Centroid Fill*

[image]

[image]